# Is SignalR possible without jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, typescript

Can TypeScript <strike>only</strike> be used to create SignalR web apps, or do we have to use jQuery? Or is there a TypeScript version of SignalR?

Answer (score 23):

SignalR has a dependency on JQuery therefore it is required that you use it.

However, there is an issue filed on the SignalR source GitHub page to re-write the JS client without the JQuery dependency.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372

Comment: TL;DR That issue has been closed. For .NET Core, use Signalr Core instead (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372#issuecomment-316150429). For .NET Framework, it seems there will be no updates: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372#issuecomment-316151028

Answer (score 11):

I made this based on react-native-signalr but without adding jQuery to window object
https://github.com/DVLP/signalr-no-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use TypeScript or Javascript client, but you have to use new version SignalR Core.